# BULK INSERT no SQL Server com colunas variáveis no CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv

Olá. Recebo arquivos *.CSV de um programa que mede a tonalidade de tinta. Se a tinta for sólida recebo um arquivo com 15 itens (spetrum no ângulo 45°), se for metálica com 36 itens (spectrum nos ângulos 25°, 45° e 75°). Eles tem em comum a informação ângulo 45°. 
Estou tentando fazer um BULK INSERT no SQLSERVER com estes CSV's. Quando o arquivo CSV possui os dois tipos de tintas, minha tabela é populada corretamente, pois os campos da tinta sólida sem informação retornam NULL. Quando  o arquivo possui somente a tinta metálica a tabela também é populada corretamente, pois possui todas a informações. Porém quando o arquivo possui somente a tinta sólida minha tabela fica fora de ordem.

A primeira linha do CSV apresenta sempre o nome das colunas. 
Existe alguma maneira de selecionar a coluna correta no BULK INSERT do SQL SERVER?

```
    CREATE TABLE TB_SERIES(
    [HDR_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CKZ_NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Model] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ColorName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Paintline] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Param4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Param5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dL* 25] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [da* 25] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [db* 25] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dC* 25] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dH* 25] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dL* 45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [da* 45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [db* 45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dC* 45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dH* 45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dL* 75] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [da* 75] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [db* 75] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dC* 75] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dH* 75] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dEe Mean] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dSparkle_area 15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dSparkle_area 45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dSparkle_area 75] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dSparkle_int 15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dSparkle_int 45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dSparkle_int 75] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dSparkle 15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dSparkle 45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dSparkle 75] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dE AUDI 25] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dE AUDI 45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dE AUDI 75] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

BULK INSERT DB_Tonalidade.dbo.TB_SERIES
    FROM 'C:\Desktop\Medições Tonalidade\Color_20-06-03 14_13_06.csv'
    WITH
        (
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
            FIRSTROW = 3
        )
```

Obrigado.

Comment: No arquivo texto (formato csv) a coluna que indica o tipo de tinta (sólida ou metálica) está sempre na mesma posição em todos os casos?

Comment: Sim, estão sempre na mesma posição. Em qualquer caso.

Comment: Uma opção é importar o conteúdo do arquivo texto (formato CSV) para uma tabela temporária com uma única coluna texto. Ou seja, cada registro do arquivo é uma linha na tabela, todo o conteúdo do registro em uma única coluna.  
Após a importação, para cada linha da tabela temporária deve-se então analisar o campo que indica o tipo de tinta e fazer a separação de campos de acordo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Vou fazer sugestão.

Comment: Ops! Tem uma falha na minha sugestão. Há como saber quando o arquivo possui somente a tinta sólida? Caso contrário, antes será necessário analisar se a primeira linha na tabela temporária tem 15 ou 36 itens, o que permitirá definir qual foi a estrutura importada.

Comment: Sim, é possível. Acho que analisar pelo tamanho da linha é melhor, pois novas tintas podem ser inseridas no sistema, sendo elas sólidas ou metalicas. Também  encontrei uma solução utilizando SSIS. Muito obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: @José Diz, muito obrigado pela dica. Finalizei o projeto, verificando pelo tamanho da linha.